# aip template, zotero, and citation undefined issues

Tags: bibliographies, citing, zotero

I am currently using an American Institute of Physics sample file downloaded [here](https://www.sharelatex.com/project/5b33a7350e0fb848bb2f6a2b)

I am also using zotero with the better BibLaTeX package to create my bibliography. I find that after exporting the bibliography, TexMaker can easily detect all the entries and they even show up as suggestions.
However, the citations are still undefined.

Here is my MWE for my file

```
\documentclass[%
 aip,
 jmp,%
 amsmath,amssymb,
%preprint,%
 reprint,%
%author-year,%
%author-numerical,%
]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files
\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point
\usepackage{bm}% bold math
\usepackage{comment}
%\usepackage[mathlines]{lineno}% Enable numbering of text and display math
%\linenumbers\relax % Commence numbering lines

\begin{document}
\section{\label{sec:level1}First-level heading}
\cite{BowenObservationultrasonicemission1991}


\bibliography{XACT Review paper}
\bibliographystyle{aipnum4-1.bst}


\end{document}
```

My .bib file MWE is as follows

```
@article{BowenObservationultrasonicemission1991,
  title = {Observation of Ultrasonic Emission from Edges of Therapeutic {{X}}-Ray Beams},
  volume = {36},
  issn = {0031-9155},
  doi = {10.1088/0031-9155/36/4/011},
  abstract = {Describes the observation of acoustic pulses generated solely by the dose gradient at the edges of a therapeutic X-ray beam in a medium consisting only of water. This effect might find application when soft-tissue regions of patients receive therapeutic X-ray doses, either to verify precisely the position of the delivered X-ray dose relative to critical tissue which must be spared as much as possible during a course of treatments, or to measure a physical characteristic of the tissue.},
  language = {en},
  number = {4},
  journal = {Physics in Medicine \& Biology},
  author = {Bowen, T. and Chen, C. X. and Liew, S. C. and Lutz, W. R. and Nasoni, R. L.},
  year = {1991},
  pages = {537},
  file = {C:\\Users\\hexagram\\Zotero\\storage\\57TFHXV2\\Bowen et al. - 1991 - Observation of ultrasonic emission from edges of t.pdf}
}
```

which was generated by Better BibLaTeX in zotero.
I have tried the following two compilation orders [image]

However I keep getting the error that the citation is undefined.

I have checked other forums for this issue (as I know it is a common one) but I could not find any solutions that worked for me so I am at this point wondering if the issue is with zotero import. Is there some issue with the way the bib file is written? Or maybe my cite command?

Comment: You are not using `biblatex`, so I have removed the tag to avoid confusion. You may get slightly better results if you tell Zotero BBT to export for BibTeX and not `biblatex` (though that need not be the case, check both outputs). On first glance the `.bib` entry looks OK. There are three possible sources of error: Normally the order `\bibliographystyle... \bibliography...` is preferred over `\bibliography... \bibnliographystyle...` (though that might just be a matter of taste). ...

Comment: **More importantly** file names with spaces are often very problematic, rename `XACT Review paper.bib` to `xact.bib`. **Finally** the argument to `\bibnliographystyle` should not include the `.bst` file ending: It should just be `\bibliographystyle{aipnum4-1}`. Change these three things and try again. If the problem persists, update your question with the new MWE and show us the `.blg` file that results from the BibTeX run (if BibTeX run it should produce this log file).